# How can my employer be a man-in-the-middle when I connect to Gmail?

Tags: encryption, tls, authentication, man-in-the-middle

I'm trying to understand SSL/TLS. What follows are a description of a scenario and a few assumptions which I hope you can confirm or refute.

**Question**

How can my employer be a man-in-the-middle when I connect to Gmail? Can he at all?

That is: is it possible for the employer to unencrypt the connection between the browser on my work computer and the employer's web proxy server, read the data in plain text for instance for virus scans, re-encrypt the data and to send it to Google without me noticing it?

Browser on employee's computer <--> employer's web proxy server <--> Gmail server

The employer can install any self-signed certificate on the company computers. It's his infrastructure after all.

**Scenario: what I am doing**

1. With a browser, open http://www.gmail.com (notice http, not https)
2. I get redirected to the Google login page: https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1
3. I enter my username and password
4. I get redirected to Gmail: https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?pli=1#inbox
5. I click on the SSL lock-icon in the browser...

...and see the following:

- Issued to: mail.google.com
- Issued by: "employer company name"
- Valid from: 01.01.2014 - 31.12.2014
- Certification path: "employer company name" --> "employer web proxy server name" --> mail.google.com

**Assumption**

I'm now assuming that the SSL lock-icon in the browser turns green, but in fact I don't have a secure connection from the browser to the Gmail server.

Is that correct?

**Sources**

I've read these sources but still don't quite understand it:

- [Is there a method to detect an active man-in-the-middle?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20871/is-there-a-method-to-detect-an-active-man-in-the-middle)
- [Preventing a spoofing man in the middle attack?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33909/preventing-a-spoofing-man-in-the-middle-attack?rq=1)
- [How does SSL/TLS work?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work?lq=1)

**Summary**

1. Is it possible for someone to be a man-in-the-middle if that someone controls the IT infrastructure? If so, how exactly?
2. Is my login and password read in plain text on the employer's web proxy server?
3. What should I check in the browser to verify that I have a secure connection from the browser all the way to the Gmail server?

*EDIT, 18.07.2014*

- Privacy is not a concern. I'm just curious about how TLS works in this particular scenario. What other means the employer has to intercept communication (keylogger etc.) are not relevant in this particular case.
- Legal matters aren't a concern. Employees are allowed to use company IT equipment for private communication within certain limits. On the other hand, the employer reserves the right to do monitoring without violating privacy.

Comment: At least your employer is fair enough to use his own name for the certificate, so you can see it. It would be much harder to find out if he copied everything from the original cert an change only the keys and checksums.

Comment: It is shocking that sites don't deploy SRP to help keep passwords secure as they assume that HTTPS is good enough http://simbo1905.wordpress.com/2014/05/16/the-secure-remote-password-protocol/

Comment: Google implements HSTS to help solve this particular issue. HSTS is HTTP Strict Transport Security which locks down the CA of the certificate Gmail uses. Use a browser with support for HSTS to help prevent man in the middle attacks.

Comment: @simbo1905 Could be an effect of Mozilla et al. pushing "Use HTTPS, it makes you secure!" to people who don't fully understand it. (That was still the case when this was posted, right?)

Comment: @gottlieb76 - are you sure about that?  I think if the employer installed a root CA certificate on the computer that you are connecitng from, HSTS would not protect against them intercepting the data in a MITM way.

Comment: @JonnyWizz - Yes and no. If the employer can get inside the very first request, then yes. But google (and others) are starting to preload browsers with a HSTS list, thwarting this type of attack. Note that HSTS prevents the change of root CA as the certificates will be pinned. If you are unsure, just check the issuer of your certificate when visiting a cite.

Comment: @gottlieb76 first you are confusing hsts and hkp. Secondly hkp deliberately doesn't protect against MITM by manually installed roots.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You are absolutely correct in your assumptions.

If you are using a computer owned and operated by your employer, they effectively have full control over your communications. Based on what you have provided, they have installed a root CA certificate that allows them to sign a certificate for Google themselves.

This isn't that uncommon in the enterprise, as it allows inspection of encrypted traffic for virus or data leaks.

To answer your three questions:

1. Yes it is very possible, and likely. How active they are at monitoring these things is unknown.
2. Your password can be read in plain text by your employer. I don't know what you mean about the web server.
3. You can check the certificate to see who signed it, as you have already done. You can also compare the fingerprint to that of Google (checked from a third party outside of business control)

Edit:

> How exactly is my employer able to unencrypt that? Could you perhaps
>   elaborate on that a bit?

You are using the bad certificate to connect to an intermediary device such as the firewall, that device is then connecting to Google using the correct certificate. The communication is encrypted from your client to the MITM, decrypted, and then re-encrypted on its way to Google.

Comment: Thank you very much for confirming my assumptions and answering the three questions! What I still don't get: I thought my browser would take Gmail's public key, encrypt everything in my browser and send it to Gmail. How exactly is my employer able to unencrypt that? Could you perhaps elaborate on that a bit?

Comment: @Lernkurve: In the case of a man in the middle, your browser will receive your employer's forged Gmail certificate instead of the real Gmail certificate. Normally, the browser would detect this situation because it's assumed to be impossible to forge a public keys issued by a credible CA, but if your company install their own root CA certificate, the browser would trust any certificates issued by the company CA and doesn't issue any warnings.

Comment: It's worth noting that in many jurisdictions this might be considered a violation of a right to privacy (see article 12 of UDHR) depending on what your employer told you about what they were doing.

Comment: @Lernkurve your browser is encrypting it with the public key from your employer's certificate.  Then your employer's network monitoring device uses the private key from the employer cert to decrypt the message (and presumably make sure you're not smuggling proprietary data out).  It then uses Google's public key to re-encrypt your message and sends it to Google.  The same process in reverse occurs for Google's response.

Comment: @DanNeely: Now, I get it. Thanks for spelling it out for me.

Comment: One minor subtlety: If you're using Chrome as your browser, it will refuse to connect to Gmail if there's a man-in-the-middle, as Chrome hard-codes rules on who can sign certificates for Google sites (see http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/update-on-attempted-man-in-middle.html). Other combinations of browser and mail provider would have no special protection, however.

Comment: @James_pic either that's no longer the case or my employer's doing something to get around it.  I just logged into gmail from Chrome at work and it's showing the use of the same bluecoat.myemployer.com cert that their proxy serves up for everything else it mitm's to monitor.

Comment: @DanNeely, it doesn't quite change the broader point of this discussion, but that's not [how SSL works](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/20803/2435). Content is encrypted with *symmetric* keys negotiated during the handshake, not the certificate key.

Comment: @symcbean In some countries email is considered as normal mail. This means that if the employer reads it, *whether encrypted or not*, and independently of whether you are using their computer or not, *is a criminal offence*. For example in Italy you'd be violating [art 616](http://www.brocardi.it/codice-penale/libro-secondo/titolo-xii/capo-iii/sezione-v/art616.html) of the criminal code; in which case the employer could be sent to prison for 1 year (3 if their knowledge of the contents of the email damaged the subject [this would probably include the employer fireing the employee])

Comment: We really need laws making signing of a forged certificate a felony, regardless of the purpose for which it's done.

Comment: @Bakuriu: The employer isn't doing anything to the e-mail though.  The data being inspected are web pages (HTTPS requests), not e-mail (SMTP+TLS or SMTP+SSL or SSMTP).  The e-mail is processed by the gmail server, all you get is a web view of it.  Trying to apply a strict interpretation would likely implicate gmail (their computers open your e-mail and convert it into an HTML page).  If gmail is permitted to handle your e-mail because you've consented, surely your employer has demanded the same consent as a condition of network access.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Do you work for the NSA's PR dept?

Comment: There's two points for the price of one in Ben's comment. (1) as a matter of Italian law, is "email" defined as "data over SMTP/POP/IMAP" or is it defined as "I know it when I see it"? If the former then the employer is off the hook. (2) what constitutes "reading" it? Mechanical manipulation for a particular purpose (reformatting, virus scanning, adding ads, grepping for terrorist words) is commonly held by the person doing it, if not always by the law, to be "not reading it". No doubt both questions have answers in Italian law, if not necessarily that would satisfy pedantic programmers.

Comment: Oh yes, and Italy has quite extensive employment law that regulates contracts between employer and employee. So even if the employer has demanded consent to do something as a condition of employment (or just as a condition of network access) I very much doubt it follows *necessarily* in Italian law that they actually have consent. This might be a value of "something" for which it does follow, then again it might not.

Comment: Yeah, I would definitely follow that you probably consented to these sorts of searches in your employment agreement.  I would suggest reviewing your employment agreement and your company's employee handbook (available from HR).

Comment: @davidHoude, do you know of any browser extensions that will flag if a SSL cert is signed by other than the well-known chain? currently I get a big green 'Secure' lock on sites that I know are being MITM'd. From my employer I'm not too fussed, but it'd be good to know...

Answer (score 21):

1 and 2 are answered by David Houde

3:

There's not actually any way to tell for sure whether *you* are securely talking to Gmail when using your company's machine (aside from auditing the machine down to the metal). Even if they didn't change the cert, they could simply modify the web browser to forward all decrypted traffic somewhere. There are a million other things they could do. It just so happens that in this case, they installed their own root certificate which allows you to see what they've done.

Comment: And even with this way, they could just call their CA-Certificate Verisign3 or something and you would neven suspect it ;-)

Comment: Exactly. So eventually the question is: who sold you your private laptop and why are you running a preinstalled Windows containing who knows what? Somewhere you have a root of trust :) (And talking about trust roots, did anyone mention CAs? :D)

Answer (score 9):

I don't see anyone mentioning it so allow me to point something out. Maybe I'm wrong but doesn't **certificate pinning** implemented in Google Chrome (there is a plugin for Firefox as well) prevents the certificate spoofing?

Related [question and answers.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29988/what-is-certificate-pinning)

Of course it is possible to sniff someones traffic if you control the infrastructure. But this is possible to some extent and in my opinion it depends on how restricted user actions are and what is the knowledge of the user. Google Chrome is the browser that can be installed within User Profile and I think it does not require administrative privilege. You can also verify the checksum of installation package to verify it hasn't been modified on-the-fly. Since **Google Chrome uses certificate pinning** regardless of Operating System cert store - **is it still vulnerable to MITM**?

I do not see any way of preventing users from using portable version of VirtualBox with client OS that will have a bunch of privacy oriented tools that will significantly elevate the chance of securing the communication to any website/domain.

Please, feel free to correct me if I'm wrong in any of the above.

### ----------

Edit.

Ok. So i found out a **solution to check if the certificate has been spoofed**. It supposedly does not work perfectly for google and apple but it might be what you are looking for in case of other domains.

To the point:

There is a site https://www.grc.com/fingerprints.htm that can **check remote certificate fingerprint for you**. You can then compare it with the one u see within your browser to check if they match. If they do not match - this cert is spoofed (`Exception is mentioned in the section *What can go wrong with this test?* on the mentioned page.`).

Here's proof it works. Browser cert:
[image]

**Fingerprint from grc.com verification**:
[image]

I think since you are mentioning something along the lines of mass-surveillance the certificate spoofing will also be on multiple https sites. In that case if one will be confirmed to be spoofed i think you can assume all of them are.

---

Next edit.

Just for the sake of completing the answer. Since it might be the case where some state or organization **modify the browser completely** and the browser **cannot be trusted** to confirm the validity of certificate. I've found a powershell function that performs an SSL connection to specified address and displays some useful information about the certificate.

Here is the code (alias is mine):

```
function Test-WebServerSSL {
[CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, Position = 0)]
        [string]$URL,
        [Parameter(Position = 1)]
        [ValidateRange(1,65535)]
        [int]$Port = 443,
        [Parameter(Position = 2)]
        [Net.WebProxy]$Proxy,
        [Parameter(Position = 3)]
        [int]$Timeout = 15000,
        [switch]$UseUserContext
    )
Add-Type @"
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
namespace PKI {
    namespace Web {
        public class WebSSL {
            public Uri OriginalURi;
            public Uri ReturnedURi;
            public X509Certificate2 Certificate;
            //public X500DistinguishedName Issuer;
            //public X500DistinguishedName Subject;
            public string Issuer;
            public string Subject;
            public string[] SubjectAlternativeNames;
            public bool CertificateIsValid;
            //public X509ChainStatus[] ErrorInformation;
            public string[] ErrorInformation;
            public HttpWebResponse Response;
        }
    }
}
"@
    $ConnectString = "https://$url`:$port"
    $WebRequest = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($ConnectString)
    $WebRequest.Proxy = $Proxy
    $WebRequest.Credentials = $null
    $WebRequest.Timeout = $Timeout
    $WebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = $true
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
    try {$Response = $WebRequest.GetResponse()}
    catch {}
    if ($WebRequest.ServicePoint.Certificate -ne $null) {
        $Cert = [Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]$WebRequest.ServicePoint.Certificate.Handle
        try {$SAN = ($Cert.Extensions | Where-Object {$_.Oid.Value -eq "2.5.29.17"}).Format(0) -split ", "}
        catch {$SAN = $null}
        $chain = New-Object Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain -ArgumentList (!$UseUserContext)
        [void]$chain.ChainPolicy.ApplicationPolicy.Add("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1")
        $Status = $chain.Build($Cert)
        New-Object PKI.Web.WebSSL -Property @{
            OriginalUri = $ConnectString;
            ReturnedUri = $Response.ResponseUri;
            Certificate = $WebRequest.ServicePoint.Certificate;
            Issuer = $WebRequest.ServicePoint.Certificate.Issuer;
            Subject = $WebRequest.ServicePoint.Certificate.Subject;
            SubjectAlternativeNames = $SAN;
            CertificateIsValid = $Status;
            Response = $Response;
            ErrorInformation = $chain.ChainStatus | ForEach-Object {$_.Status}
        }
        $chain.Reset()
        [Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = $null
    } else {
        Write-Error $Error[0]
    }
}

Set-Alias TSSL Test-WebServerSSL
```

You can paste it in the powershell console - this will register the function for the time of current session (until you close the powershell console window so you leave no trace).

After that you can type in the same window:

```
TSSL www.ipko.pl
```

The output will look like that:
[image]

I've found a function code [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:bhoxi3G8YckJ:en-us.sysadmins.lv/Lists/Posts/ViewPost.aspx%3FID%3D60&client=firefox-a&hl=en&strip=1).

Comment: The way that companies can prevent users from installing Virtual Box is to prevent them from installing Virtual Box - either by preventing all software installs, or using a whitelist of acceptable applications. Likewise, boot from USB can be disabled.

Comment: @Johnny Yeah. That's quite obvious. If you got the control over GroupPolicy, you have admin rights and so on - you can prevent users from installing programs. You can deny them modification access to certain parts of registry. Still you will not be able to prevent them from executing whatever the program they like and that is why I've specifically stated that they can use `**portable**` version of Virtual Box. Portable means it works without installation hence no system-modification-rights are needed.

Comment: Interesting. Certificate pinning should detect it. But unfortunately, I can't test it. I can't put any unauthorized software on the machine -- not even a portable version of Google Chrome.

Comment: @Lernkurve I've edited my answer. Please take a look - maybe that will satisfy your need to confirm if the certificate has been spoofed or not.

Comment: mnmnc, it turns out pinning is not enforced for certificates chained from private anchors, see http://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/security-faq#TOC-How-does-key-pinning-interact-with-local-proxies-and-filters- (via [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/AskNetsec/comments/26e18a/how_to_bypass_firefoxchromes_ssl_validation/chqcjt5))

Comment: @Angel :/ That is a sad news. It's like they are all cooperating to rape our privacy ;) Thank you very much for clarification. I do appreciate it. I thought with cert-pinning we are a bit more secure.

Comment: well, there are _good_ uses for that, such as pentesting an application without the https cert. On the bright side, you should be able to view those inserted entries on your certificate store. If people needed to compile a patched chromium I wouldn't be much surprised that they used horrible hacks like `if  (cert->organization contains mycompany) return trusted;` (and the browser would fell out of upstream updates)

Comment: @mnmnc The [https://www.grc.com/fingerprints.htm](https://www.grc.com/fingerprints.htm) was very useful. The fingerprints are indeed different.

Comment: I remember reading that certificate pinning in Chrome intentionally does not warn if a cert is signed with a specially installed root CA, because _this is a perfectly legitimate use-case_. Certificate pinning is designed to protect against CA compromise. It is not designed to stop you from intentionally allowing a MitM, because that's the user's call (in this case it's a company computer, so the company gets to make the call). Also, as certificate stores are as protected as the browser, pinning _can't_ be effective against someone adding new root CAs, and there's no reason it should be.

Comment: Corrected the script (New-Object PKI.Web.WebSSL: The value supplied is not valid), automated comparison with grc.com results. https://gist.github.com/ilatypov/993f993a05370cc9c0cb2347a2d04568

Answer (score 7):

As others pointed out: Yes, it is possible and it is being done in this case.

Trying to detail more the steps involved in this MITM:

You know that certificate 028CA85E6765… belongs to gmail because a CA (GeoTrust, Verisign…) has asserted that it does. Your OS/browser contain a list of CAs it trust to do the right thing (not to lie, be properly secured…).

- Your employer has installed in your computer its own CA.
- When you connect to accounts.google.com with TLS, the proxy issues itself a new certificate for `accounts.google.com` signed by that CA (if it doesn't already have one).
- Your connection to the proxy is done using the fake `accounts.google.com` certificate. The proxy meddles with the content as it whishes, then connects to the real `accounts.google.com` (using Google's certificate) and sends back and forth the contents you and gmail give to each other.
- As your computer trusts the proxy CA, it considers that the `accounts.google.com` certificate issued by your employer is legitimate¹ thus why there are no warnings.

¹ Most people would consider it is not legitimate because it's not Google's certificate, but it *is* the certificate expected inside this company. Employees may disagree it is desirable, though. :-)

Comment: "`certificate 028CA85E6765`" Yeah I thought the same. Trouble is, Google uses dozens of certificates. Why they go through the trouble of having many certificates at the same time even if most of them are nowhere near expiring is a mystery to me, but they do. I think the best thing to do is compare fingerprints from the CA.

Comment: @Luc it probably boils down to different clusters/datacenters. AS you pointed out, the right thing for these big companies with many certificates is to check the CA. They usually have their own intermediate authoritym too (eg. “Google Internet Authority G2”)

Answer (score 6):

To add to other answers, the only way to ensure, with a reasonable certainty, that you have a secure connection from your browser to the web server, is to use your own equipment. The employer-owned equipment and network is not under your control, and it may be difficult to determine what is included in their standard operating system and applications. Even if it's illegal in the country you are at, if privacy is a concern, you probably should use your mobile phone or personal laptop.